# ERC20 : problem with transferFrom

Tags: solidity, erc-20, staking

I am trying to make a staking application DApp and I am facing this problem when I launch the DApp:

[image]

Obviously, it's a problem of balance, this one is not enough big. I red this link too:
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/example-on-how-to-use-erc20-token-in-another-contract/1682

In my SC of staking, I use this function to stake:

[image]

Everything works fine in Remix.

I don't understand very well how to set the balance to be greater than the transfer amount. Can I do this in the UI, in the 2_deploy_contracts.js?

This is my 2_deploy_contracts.js:

[image]

I set the initialStakeCoinSupply in SC token too:

```
contract StakeCoin is ERC20, Ownable {


uint256 public initialStakeCoinSupply = 1000000000000000000000000;


/**
    @notice the constructor for the Staking coin token
    @dev the owner is the admin of the interface
    @param initialStakeCoinSupply The amount of initial tokens to mint on construction
    <!> it works with Remix!
*/
constructor(uint initialStakeCoinSupply) ERC20("Stake Coin Token", "STC") {
    _mint(owner(), initialStakeCoinSupply);
}

/**
 *   @notice produces some tokens for a smart contract
 *   @param to address of the recipient
 *   @param value amount of tokens to produce
 *   @return boolean did we produce some tokens?
 *  <!> it works with Remix!
 */
function mint(address to, uint256 value) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    _mint(to, value);
    return true;
}
```

If you have a piece of advice to give me, don't hesitate please,

Comment: You can’t approve and transferfrom in the same function /transaction

Comment: Hello, if I understand well, I have to find a way to call approve either from another function in my staking contract (approve will be a function from ERC20 tokens) or from my App.js with this. state. StakeCoin. methods. approve (…) for exemple, is it right?

Comment: the approve function can only be called by the owner directly from the original used erc20 contract. When u call approve in your contract then the sender is the contract and not the original owner

Comment: The approve call cannot be forwarded